# How do I scroll the user chat during a multiplayer match in CUBE 2: SAUERBRATEN?

Tags: cube-2-sauerbraten

I know I can scroll the server log using the <kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>-</kbd> buttons. I tried holding the alt key but it did not have any effect. I often need to read previous messages from other players and want to scroll up the lower chat, without success, so I lose important messages.

Side question: is there a log file with the chat in it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the <kbd>F11</kbd> key to overlay a more complete (as defined by the filters in options-> console) log window on the game screen, which is then scrollable with <kbd>+</kbd> <kbd>-</kbd>.